# Confusion in learning WebServices.!

Tags: java, web-services, rest, soap

Here is the thing, i read lot of websites regarding web Services, and even i am able to execute the web services in my eclipse as well, but my i have some doubts which i cannot clear in via google.

They are 2 types of web services in java, SOAP and RESTfull, i know the differences between, but,  what is this REST, JAX-RS, Axis2,Jax-WS 2.0.., bla bla some CFX ?

While am executing the web service program i am just writing and getting the output but i am not sure what type of web service i am writing (SOAP/RESTful), can you please explain when to consider Axis2 and Jax-ws..?

Thank you so much

Comment: JAX-RS, Axis2,Jax-WS,CXF provide the implementation of SOAP and RESTfull web services. JAX-WS is for implementing the SOAP based web services and JAX-RS for RESTfull web services. Axis2 provide SOAP web service implementation and CXF provides SOAP and REST both implementation.

Comment: Mudit, Its very clear, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic explanation of web service is very simple - services exposed over web (application protocols running over TCP/IP). All of your questions are regarding different ways in which these
services can be accessed and developed. There are different [specifications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_service_specifications) for different kinds of web services. In each platform for developing web services of course there is an evolution of technologies (JAX-RPC,JAX-WS), different implementations and different libraries.
Especially in Java world you can say problem of plenty or spoilt for choice depending upon which side you are :-)

A rather overwhelming and pictorial reference can be found [here](http://www.innoq.com/de/ws-standards-poster/innoQ%20WS-Standards%20Poster%202007-02.pdf) for all these specifications